# PHP, PDO => MSSQL with 2 instances

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

i wrote a simple script to query some data from a MSSQL-Express 2012 Server.
All workes fine with the first instance:

```
$host = "192.168.13.3\test1";
$user = "sa";
$passwd = "test1";
self::$instance = new PDO ("dblib:host=$host","$user","$passwd");
```

but if I try to connect to my second Instance like:

```
$host = "192.168.13.3\test2";
$user = "sa";
$passwd = "test2";
self::$instance = new PDO ("dblib:host=$host","$user","$passwd");
```

I get this error:

```
[message:protected] => SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 20009
```

With MSSQL-Server-Management-Tool I can access both instances without problems.
Has somebody a hint where i can find my failure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you use the same user for both but a different password...

Comment: I have to ask. TCP/IP is enabled for that server, right?